# Valgrind result explaination

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

i have a part of code in a bigger program that when and when i use the part that i ran trough valgrind  i get seg faults later in the program.

I isolated the call to function that does some TAG manipulations. Can someone explain to me if this output is problematic?

[http://pastebin.com/5J6PHxSs][1]

and this is the code:

```
  std::string Tag::GetDataAsString()
  {
     if(IsDataAvailable() <=0)
       return "";
     std::string retData="";
     std::vector<byte>& tmp = *this->Data;

     for(int i=0, length = tmp.size(); i!=length; ++i)
     {
         if(tmp[i] != 0x00)
             retData+=tmp[i];
         else
             break;
     }

     return retData;
}
```

**Edit 1**

To explain:
 Data is: std::vector* Data which is allocated when needed.
 std::vector& tmp = *this->Data; // this is only that they probably did not use () :D

I'm just trying to make some code work that someone else wrote.

What i know that in the main() method Settings::GetInstance() is called which reads from file some data that is written in tags. Tag is a class that does manipulation of tags, which can be nested or contain data, thats why i believe there is a dynamic alocation of Data and Vector of sub tags.

So what happens, there is a method:

```
LoadFromTaggedDump( TagCollection & coll )
{
     SomeData scr;
     Tag* someTag;
     std::vector<SomeData*>& tmpVect = *_localizedSomeDb; 
     for(int id = 0, dbLen = tmpVect.size(); id != dbLen; ++id)
     {
                 Tag* tmp;
         someTag= coll.GetTag(SOME_TAG | id);
        if(someTag== NULL)                
              continue;
        tmpVect[id]->SomeDat[i]=tmp->GetDataAsString();
      }
 }
```

So valgrind finds some losses in GetDataAsString() which is enclosed and should be all cleared.

And i don't understand why there would something be lost in the operator new?

Comment: are you saying this program runs fine but crashes under valgrind?

Comment: BTW *this->Data looks very odd. Its the same as 'Data'. If thats your convention for member variable 'naming' change it.

Comment: Please avoid pointers "*this->Data;" - likely useless

Comment: The valgrind output is useless, having this example

Comment: To explain. Data is: std::vector<byte>* Data which is allocated when needed.

Comment: Now the valgrind output realy does not mean anything :S as this location that it reports is nonsense. i have deleted everything on exit and now it reports 0 errors. But still the program sometimes Segfaults or reports Invalid instruction. The program runs on embedded linux with uclibc... Could it be something with the distro?